# Python: Binding method

Tags: python, binding, types, methods, bind

In following example I am trying to bind a method object via *types.MethodType(...)*. It does not seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
import types

class Base:
    def payload(self, *args): 
        print "Base:payload"

class Drvd(Base):
    def iter(self, func):
        derived_func = types.MethodType(func, self, Drvd) # bind
        print "drvd_func:", derived_func 
        derived_func() # result:  calls Base:payload 
                       # expected:calls Drvd:payload; why???
    def payload(self, *args):
        print "Drvd:payload"

derived   = Drvd()           
base_func = Base.payload      
print "base_func:", base_func
derived.iter(base_func)  # pass unbound method object
```

The output shows:

base_func: <unbound method Base.payload>
drvd_func: <bound method Drvd.payload of <**main**.Drvd instance at 0x00B51648>>
Base:payload

Comment: Since the subclass inherits the superclass function, why are you doing this?  What's the point?

Comment: Alex has pointed out, that the original unbound method Base.payload cannot be converted to another classes member function with the same name. Even with inherited classes. 

I am currently setting up a tree iteration. Looks like I should use a Visitor/Multimethod approach or have IDs per payload handler with a dispatcher per node. It will be used to store XML output from a Sax parser-

Comment: Use Visitor whenever possible.  Avoid magic.

Answer (score 2):

You're specifically requesting the use of the underlying function (`im_func`) of `Base.payload`, with a fake `im_class` of `Drvd`.  Add after the existing `print` in `iter`:

```
    print "w/class:", derived_func.im_class
    print "w/func:", derived_func.im_func
```

and you'll see the total output as:

```
$ python bou.py 
base_func: <unbound method Base.payload>
drvd_func: <bound method Drvd.payload of <__main__.Drvd instance at 0x24a918>>
w/class: __main__.Drvd
w/func: <unbound method Base.payload>
Base:payload
```

i.e., as you've asked, the underlying code being used is indeed `Base.payload` -- which is also what you observe in the call.

From `Base.payload` there is no direct way to get to `Drvd.payload` except by getting the name and using it to do a `getattr` on `self` (a `Drvd` instance), or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. The name of the passed unbound function is indeed the only link amongst Base and Drvd implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Because you passed Base's payload (not Drvd's) to iter!

Hint:

```
print "%s: Base:payload"%repr(self)
```

Kudos for creating an accursed chimera of a thing, though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do - but to me it's working as I'd expect. You are binding Base.payload to Drvd - from your print out you can see it is binding correctly to your Drvd instance. I'm not sure why you are then expecting it to call Drvd.payload - you have bound the function object Base.payload. It is always going to be that function.

[edit: just to add - it might be helpful if you say what your trying to do in general terms. What you're doing at the moment doesn't make much sense - Python has inheritence so if you want to override the payload method you can just do it - you don't need to do any manual binding.]

Comment: I am trying to reduce coding effort on tarversing a treelike structure of nodes compared to a visitor-pattern or multimethod approach. It seems to become a hack though on bending pythons underlying method signatures.